# Google Maps not Centering Based on Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps

All,
I've got the following code to display my maps:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
var oldonload = window.onload; 
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){ 
    window.onload = func
} else { 
    window.onload = function() {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
}

var map,
    infowin=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'moin'});
function loadMap() 
{
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map_vendor'),
    {   
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, 
                                    <?php echo $long; ?>)
    });

  addPoints(myStores);
}

function addPoints( points )
{  
  //var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for ( var p = 0; p < points.length; ++p )
  {
    var pointData = points[p];
    if ( pointData == null ) {map.fitBounds(bounds);return; }
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng( pointData.latitude, pointData.longitude );
    //bounds.union(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(point));
    createMarker( point,  pointData.html );
  }
  //map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function createMarker(point,  popuphtml) 
{
  var popuphtml = "<div id=\"popup\">" + popuphtml + "<\/div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position:point,
      map:map
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowin.setContent(popuphtml)
      infowin.open(map,marker);
    });

}

function Store( lat, long, text )
{
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = long;
    this.html = text;
}

var myStores = [<?php echo $jsData;?>, null];
addLoadEvent(loadMap);
</script>
```

The $jsData is set with the following code:

```
$lat = get_post_meta($post->ID,'latitude',TRUE);
$long = get_post_meta($post->ID,'longitude',TRUE);
$post_id = $post->ID;
$get_post_info = get_post($post_id); 
$name = $get_post_info->post_title;
$jsData = $jsData . "new Store( $lat, $long, '$name' ),\n";
```

The point gets displayed correctly however my map isn't being centered correctly. My maps is always southeast from the location of the point and just a little but I'd like for it to be centered on the point. How can I go about doing this?

EDIT: Here is the CSS that you requested. It's a theme so I'm sorry if it's crazy:

```
#map_vendor{
padding:10px;
width:925px;
height:300px;
}
.styled-image, .the-post-image figure, .styled-slideshow, .gallery .gallery-icon a { 
border-color: #C9CBCD;
background: #F7F7F7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#E7E8EB));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff,  #E7E8EB);
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #E7E8EB);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#fff, #E7E8EB);  
}
.styled-image, .the-post-image a figure, .gallery .gallery-icon a { 
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out; 
transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out; 
}
.styled-image, .the-post-image figure, .styled-slideshow, .gallery .gallery-icon a { 
display: block; display: inline-block; outline: none; padding: 6px;
border: 2px solid #C9CBCD; border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; /* border radius */
/* gradient background */
background: #F7F7F7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#E7E8EB));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff,  #E7E8EB);
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #E7E8EB);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#fff, #E7E8EB);    
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* box shadow */
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;   /* smoother borders with webkit */ 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "point" mean?

Currently you set the center to $lat and $lng, but there is no marker(point?) at this position(unless inside $jsData will be the same coordinates).

Comment: I've updated my original question so you can see that. However you are correct. The $jsData has the same coordinates as I'm trying to set the center of the map.

Comment: Sorry, please provide a demo of the issue, otherwise I can't help you. I was testing this, the marker(of course) is centered. No matter if zoom is 1 or 15, he will always be placed at the same position at the viewport, so he must be centered(in my testcase).

Comment: It's on my localhost so I can't really show you. I tried to create a jsfiddle to see if it worked but I must be missing something because it isn't loading correctly. I tried to manually hardcode in the values and it still wasn't showing up correctly on my site. Here is the jsfiddle so you can see if you can get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrjmt/

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not sure what is going on because I copied the code from your Fiddle and it still displays it off center. If/When I make my site live I'll check back here if it still isn't working. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Maybe you have some CSS inside your page that forces the offset.

Comment: I might but what would actually cause the map to offset like that? Padding? Margin?

Comment: I've updated my questions with the CSS that was being applied to the map.